# AKKA TCP: Dropping write because queue is full

Tags: java, tcp, akka, playframework-2.6, akka-tcp

I connect to a TCP service using akka-tcp
In very concurrent requests service crashes with this exception:

```
2018/03/28 13:28:56 +0430 - [INFO] - from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-30 
CommandFailed(Write(ByteString(123, 34, 116, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 110, 101, 119, 79, 114, 100, 101, 114, 34, 44, 34, 109, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101, 73, 100, 34, 58, 34, 49, 99, 52, 54, 55, 50, 49, 97, 45, 102, 101, 51, 97, 45, 52, 100, 50, 48, 45, 57, 100, 98, 102, 45, 102, 98, 50, 56, 101, 97, 56, 52, 100, 48, 55, 56, 34, 44, 34, 97, 99, 99, 111, 117, 110, 116, 78, 117, 109, 98, 101, 114, 34, 58, 34, 49, 54, 56, 56, 48, 49, 49, 53, 55, 50, 53, 32, 32)... and [261] more,NoAck(null))) because of Dropping write because queue is full
```

I try to increase my server read and write socket buffer according to this article:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tcp-tuning/

but my problem still exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem were because of buffer socket size of server that serves TCP service.
After increasing the buffer size of both servers the problem resolved.
see this:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tcp-tuning/